# Django Displaying Data from database

Tags: python, django

I am using Django and I am trying to making a template tag to display the data from my database (sqlite3). So far this is my models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, help_text = u'The user who supplied this answer')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, help_text = u"The question that this is an answer to")
    runid = models.CharField(u'RunID', help_text = u"The RunID (ie. year)", max_length=32)
    answer = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Answer(%s: %s, %s)" % (self.question.number, self.subject.surname, self.subject.givenname)
```

and here is my view.py

```
def answer_list(request):
    answer_info = Answer.objects.all()

    answer_data = {
    "answer_detail" : answer_info
    }

print answer_data
 return render_to_response('quizzes.html'', answer_data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

to display the information that is in the database how should my quizzes.html template look like?
so far I have this

```
{% for answer_list in answer_detail %}
<h3>{{ answer_list.question }}</h3>
<p>{{ answer_list.answer }}
{{ answer_list.runid }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I believe there is something slightly wrong with my for loop but unsure of what?

Comment: Have you gone through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/)? The first argument to `render_to_response` is the template name, not the URL.

Answer (score 3):

`answers_detail` in your tag is not the same as the `"answer_detail"` key that you pass in your context dict. There's an extra s in the tag version.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the problem. What should the blank be in {% for ______ in answer_detail %}

Comment: It's an arbitrary name. You can put down whatever you like, then as long as you reference it with the same name, that won't be a problem.

Comment: That is what I thought. I dont understand why the db data is display in my template.

Comment: No I think maybe its in my URLS? my quizzes template is

url(r'quizzes/$', (TemplateView.as_view(template_name="quizzes.html"))),

Comment: I think looking at one of the popular tutorials might be a good use of time. Try replacing that classed based view reference in your urlconf with `url(r'quizzes/$', path.to.answer_list)`.